# Spacing of awesome-cv subsection

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, fontawesome, awesome-cv

I'm using the [awesome-cv](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) document class and noticed a problem with the `\cvsubsection` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}
\begin{document}

\cvsubsection{Sub A}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {Degree} % Degree
    {Institution} % Institution
    {Location} % Location
    {99/9999} % Date(s)
    {
        \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
            \item{foobar}
            \item{barfoo}
        \end{cvitems}
    } 
    \cventry
    {Degree} % Degree
    {Institution} % Institution
    {Location} % Location
    {99/9999} % Date(s)
    {
        \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
            \item{foobar}
            \item{barfoo}
        \end{cvitems}   
    } 

\end{cventries}

\cvsubsection{SubB}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {Degree} % Degree
    {Institution} % Institution
    {Location} % Location
    {99/9999} % Date(s)
    {
        \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
            \item{foobar}
            \item{barfoo}
        \end{cvitems}
    } 
\end{cventries}
\cvsubsection{SubC}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {Degree} % Degree
    {Institution} % Institution
    {Location} % Location
    {99/9999} % Date(s)
    {
        \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
            \item{foobar}
            \item{barfoo}
        \end{cvitems}
    }
    \cventry
    {Degree} % Degree
    {Institution} % Institution
    {Location} % Location
    {99/9999} % Date(s)
    {
        \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
            \item{foobar}
            \item{barfoo}
        \end{cvitems}
    } 
\end{cventries}
\cvsubsection{SubD}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {Degree} % Degree
    {Institution} % Institution
    {Location} % Location
    {99/9999} % Date(s)
    {
        \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
            \item{foobar}
            \item{barfoo}
        \end{cvitems}
    } 
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

[image: Note the smaller vertical spacing before SubB and SubD]

As you can see, when there are two or more `\cventry`s, the spacing before the `\cvsubsection` becomes too small. 
The document clas can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV), but here is a shortened version, just enough for my example above.

I found out that omitting the package `fontawesome` in the document class leads to equal vertical spacing before all subsections. How could I fix the problem when using `fontawesome`?

```
%% Start of file `awesome-cv.cls'.
% Awesome CV Class File
%
% This class has been downloaded from:
% https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV
%
% Author:
% Claud D. Park <posquit0.bj@gmail.com>
% http://www.posquit0.com
%
% Notes:
% 1) This class file defines the structure and layout of the template file (cv.tex, resume.tex).
% 2) It has been written in such a way that under most circumstances you 
% should not need to edit it.
%
% Class license:
% LPPL v1.3c (http://www.latex-project.org/lppl)
%


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesClass{awesome-cv}[2016/01/30 v1.5 Awesome Curriculum Vitae Class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Class options
%
% (need to be done before the external package loading, for example because
% we need \paperwidth, \paperheight and \@ptsize to be defined before loading
% geometry and fancyhdr)
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Inherit options of article
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                3rd party packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Needed to make fixed length table
\RequirePackage{array}
% Needed to handle list environment
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% Needed to handle text alignment
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
% Needed to configure page layout
\RequirePackage{geometry}
% Needed to make header & footer effeciently
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
% Needed to manage colors
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
% Needed to use \ifxetex-\else-\fi statement
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
% Needed to use \if-\then-\else statement
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
% Needed to use a toolbox of programming tools
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
% Needed to change line spacing in specific environment
\RequirePackage{setspace}
% Needed to use icons from font-awesome
% (https://github.com/posquit0/latex-fontawesome)
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
% Needed to deal a paragraphs
\RequirePackage{parskip}
% Needed to deal hyperlink
\RequirePackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for layout
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Page Layout
% Configure page margins with geometry
\geometry{left=2.0cm, top=1.5cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, footskip=.5cm}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Gray-scale colors
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}
% Text colors
\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
\colorlet{text}{darkgray}
\colorlet{graytext}{gray}
\colorlet{lighttext}{lightgray}
% Awesome colors
\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for styles
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Configure styles for each CV elements
% For fundamental structures
\newcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\scshape\textcolor{text}{#1}}}

% For elements of entry
\newcommand*{\entrytitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\scshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrydatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\slshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\slshape\color{awesome} #1}}
\newcommand*{\descriptionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\upshape\color{text} #1}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for extra
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Define helper macros a user can change easily

% Others
\newcommand{\acvSectionTopSkip}{3mm}
\newcommand{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}{2.5mm}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for utilities
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Use to align an element of tabular table
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% Use to execute conditional statements by checking empty string
\newcommand*{\ifempty}[3]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for elements of CV structure
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Define a subsection for CV
% Usage: \cvsubsection{<subsection-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-3mm}
  \subsectionstyle{#1}
  \phantomsection
}
% Define an environment for cventry
\newenvironment{cventries}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
}
```

Comment: Add empty lines between the  \cv-blocks. The class is missing a lot \par commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: never thought that adding a blank line between two `\cventry` blocks could fix the behavior of the object that follows those. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments